# Replace sum or subtraction of momentum vectors with an equivalent vector

Tags: momentum

[image]

For the diagram, how would I replace the sum or difference of two momentum vectors with an equivalent momentum vector?  So, for example in the x-direction:

$$m_e u_e cos\beta = m_1 u_1 cos\beta + m_2 u_2 cos\beta \tag{1}$$

and in the y-direction,

$$m_e u_e sin\beta = m_1 u_1 sin\beta - m_2 u_2 sin\beta \tag{2}$$

where $m_e$ is the mass and $u_e$ is the velocity for the equivalent single vector. What I find confusing is if Eqns 1 and 2 are simplified further, then the following is obtained,

$$m_e u_e  = m_1 u_1  + m_2 u_2  \tag{3}$$

$$m_e u_e  = m_1 u_1  - m_2 u_2  \tag{4}$$

Obviously something is not correct.  I'm not sure if I can make this equivalency but if possible, how would I correctly setup the equations to solve for $m_e$ and $u_e$?

Comment: What is the angle $\beta$? Are both $m_1$ and $m_2$ traveling in the same direction? Why are you subtracting in equation (2)? A diagram of the problem would help clear up these confusions.

Comment: Diagram has been added.

Comment: If $m_1$ and $m_2$ are different and $v_1$ and $v_2$ are different then there is no simplification that can be done other than $(m_1 v_1 + m_2 v_2) \cos \beta$ since you cannot factor out anything else.

Comment: Since my goal is to compare velocities before the collision with after the collision ($v_m$ - see comment below), then I think maybe what I should do is just define an average velocity before the collision.

Answer (score 1):

The resultant vector does not have the same angle as the vectors being summed. Equation (1) should be
$$m_eu_e\cos\alpha = m_1u_1\cos\beta + m_2u_2\cos\beta$$
and similarly for equation (2).

Comment: What I posted was only the LHS of the momentum eqn.  For Eqn. 1, the full equation is:

$$m_1 u_1 cos\beta + m_2 u_2 cos\beta = (m_1 + m_2)v_m cos\alpha  $$

What I was hoping to do was to combine the LHS  using $m_eu_e$ and then compare $u_e$ with $v_m$.  This is not an elastic collision.  I'm trying to come up with a kind of coefficient of restitution but based on a single stream - hence the reason for wanting to combine the incoming streams. I was hoping to get an equivalent vector for the LHS which is prior to the collision.

Comment: So, ultimately something like:

$$m_e u_e cos\beta = (m_1 + m_2)v_m cos\alpha$$

So, I need to figure out what $m_e$ and $u_e$ are.

Comment: @rdemyan I don't understand what it is you're trying to calculate. The sum of the two incoming momentum vectors (with angles $\pm\beta$) is the momentum vector after collision (with angle $\alpha$). I don't see any way, nor any point, in trying to combine the incoming vectors into one.

Comment: I am trying to combine the two terms on the left hand side into an equivalent single term.  Is it possible to write the following for the x-direction momentum?

$$m_1u_1cos\beta + m_2u_2cos\beta = (m_1+m_2)u_{ave}cos\beta$$

Comment: @rdemyan Unless the initial vectors are parallel, their sum will not be parallel to either vector. This means that the combined vectors cannot have the same angle as either of the initial vectors. The $\beta$ in the combined form can't mean anything because there's no vector with that angle except one of the initial vectors. The vector you're trying to calculate seems meaningless to me. The actual combined momentum vector is the momentum after the collision with angle $\alpha$.

Comment: But the equation:

$$m_1u_1cos\beta + m_2u_2cos\beta = (m_1+m_2)u_{ave}cos\beta$$

is the momentum in the x direction. So these x momentum vectors are parallel are they not?

Comment: @rdemyan No. The total momentum is not parallel to either of the initial vectors. Collisions change the direction of motion of the colliding objects, so you can't use the same angle as before the collision.

Comment: @rdemyan The angle $\beta$ is the angle off the x-axis for *ONE* of the initial vectors. The other initial vector has an angle of $-\beta$. What you are trying to do is set the total momentum after the collision to be parallel to *one* of the initial momentum vectors. The only way this can happen is if the other initial momentum vector is zero.

Comment: I'm not trying to set the total momentum after the collision to be equal.  I'm setting x direction momentums before and after the collision equal.
The x-momentum equation for the incoming streams would be set equal to the x momentum of the exit stream.  So,

$$ (m_1+m_2)u_{ave}cos\beta =  (m_1 + m_2)v_m cos\alpha$$

Comment: @rdemyan $u_{ave} = (m_1u_1+m_2v_2)/(m_1+m_2).$ Notice that if you substitute this into your equation, it's exactly the same as adding the initial momemta.

Comment: I think you meant $m_2u_2$ and not $m_2v_2$.  My question is part of a much bigger problem that I am working on.  The reason I am doing this is because I know what $\frac{v_m}{u_{ave}}$ is.  The actual problem has backflow in the diagram shown because of a stagnation point.  This makes the problem much more difficult.  I did originally post the full problem, but the moderators made me take it down.  So I only posted this portion.  I know what you are saying with your last post, but it sounds like you agree with me now that I can do what I'm suggesting even if you are not sure why. Correct?

Comment: @rdemyan If it's useful, go ahead and use it. I had to google the terms "backflow" and "stagnation point" to discover that this is a fluid dynamics problem. From the diagram and description, I thought the was a school problem about an inelastic collision of two particles--hence my confusion about the strategy you were pursuing.

Comment: @rdemyan Actually, I'm skeptical again. From the y equation, $v_{ave} = (m_1u_1 - m_2u_2)/(m_1 + m_2)$. So, I still don't think there's a consistent, meaningful value that can be assigned.